# Exceptions in Thread

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

StackOverflow, Hello!
I can't figure out why Eclipse keeps erroring me with this:
Console:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at myPanel.paintComponent(Animatia.java:59)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Code:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;




public class Yeah {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    myFrame frame = new myFrame();
    }
}
class myFrame extends JFrame
{
public myFrame()
{
myPanel np = new myPanel(); 
Container cont = getContentPane();
cont.add(np);
setBounds(250, 250, 250, 250);
setVisible(true);
}
}
class myPanel extends JPanel {

private int x=0,y=1555;
private Image img;
public myPanel()
{
Timer nt = new Timer(1,new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        x++;
        y--;
        repaint();

    }
});

nt.start();
try
{
img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\1\\Downloads\\skin.png"));
}
catch(IOException exp) {}
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
{
gr.clearRect(x-1, y-1, img.getWidth(null)+1, img.getHeight(null)+1);
gr.drawImage(img,x,y,null);
}
}
```

I don't get why my Console Is filled with those - i thought that had something to do with import...
May Somebody please tell me what should I fix in this code?
P.s. Can you also tell me if StackOverflow has spoilers for these reasons? 
P.P.S. I'm new to Java so please don't judge me if I make silly mistakes.

Comment: It says `NullPointerException` in your `paintComponent` method. Some of those methods you are calling, `getWidth`, `getHeight` and `drawImage`, at least one of them don't like `null` value getting passed to them. So check documentations again.

Comment: Well, eclipse thinks it's fine with null, but still thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: What is at line 59 in animatia.java?

Comment: Not Eclipse but Java thinks that it is ok to pass `null`. Eclipse is not a language, compiler or an interpreter. It's an IDE. It calls `javac` command to build your Java code. And, constraints such as that are not checked because it requires evaluation of every variable to be able to check such constraints. That's why it's a RuntimeError and not a compile time error.

Comment: Fildor, thats it                                               gr.clearRect(x-1, y-1, img.getWidth(null)+1, img.getHeight(null)+1);

Comment: So yeah, apparently the whole problem is in the "ClearRect" thing

Answer (score 0):

Do not swallow exceptions! I bet your 'img' is null. But you mute away the IOException. So if there is one, img is still null and subsequent calls on the reference -  for example 'img.height()' - will throw an NPE.

Comment: Umm.. I'm sorry, can you explain it for a noob?                          It's just that i have a class and a directory for my Image

Answer (score 0):

NeverMind Already, I fixed it myself - the problem was in (Public *void* myPanel();)
void was the odd one.